# Dynamic mysql -> excel export

Tags: php, mysql, phpspreadsheet

First off all - a "normal" export and writing an Excel file using phpspreadsheet works like a charm.
What I can't find out is how to do this in a dynamic way.
"Dynamic" means not manually defining the headlines in `row1` and not defining manually the data columns from mysql.

What I've done (tried):

```
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setTitle('test');

if ($result = $mysqli -> query($sql)) {
    $co = 'A';
    $ro = '1';
    while ($fieldinfo = $result -> fetch_field()) {
        // printf("$col.$row %s\n", $fieldinfo -> name);
        $sheet->setCellValue($co.$ro, $fieldinfo -> name);
        $$co = $fieldinfo -> name;
        $co++;
        }
    $result -> free_result();
}
```

This creates an excel file with all field names like defined in the mysql view/statement.
The challenge is to put date in column by column without creating them by code.
What I've done is to generate a variable for each column. So `$A = firstname`, `$B = name`, etc.

My idea was to address this variable by something like "first column is 'A' then I've to address the variable `$A`. But dynamically call variables doesn't work somehow

```
$sheet->setCellValue($co.$ro, $row[$cuco]);
```

`$cuco` (current column) should be `$cuco = '$'.$A`, but then the value of `$cuco` will be `$A` and the resolved variable `$A` which should be "firstname" i.e.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/accessing-cells/#looping-through-cells - loop through the rows like if it was a database result and set or get the values.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done is add a comment to each column in the database that corresponds to the heading I want for that column. An additional query will give you that data which you may then use to populate the header row.

Here's the function I use FWIW:

```
//
// Returns an array indexed by column names with the column comment,
// if any, as the value from the table name that is passed - columns
// that do not have a comment are not included in the returned array
//

public function get_column_comments($table) {

$ColsQ = $this->database->prepare('SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `' . $table . '`');
$ColsQ->execute();
$ColsD = $ColsQ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($ColsD as $col) {

    if (empty($col['Comment'])) {continue;}  // ignore columns without a comment

    $cols[$col['Field']] = $col['Comment'];
}

return $cols;

}  // end of get_column_comments function
```